# How to return back an element of list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have these three lists in my app, but I can return only one of them, how can I do that to the three of them?

```
class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
TaskList(this._tasks, this._starTime, this._endTime, this._onClick);

final List<Task> _tasks;
final List<Task> _starTime;
final List<Task> _endTime;
final _onClick;


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView(
    children: _tasks.map((task)
    {
      return TaskItem(task,_starTime,_endTime,_onClick);
    }
    ).toList());

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` only accept one List, so to do this you need to combine all the list like

```
  List<String> list1 = ['A', 'B'];
  List<String> list2 = ['C', 'D'];
  List<String> list3 = ['E', 'F'];
  var newList = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3];
  print(newList);
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

Now use `newList` inside `ListView` to render `List`

**Code:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var _newList = [..._tasks, ..._starTime, ..._endTime];
return ListView(
    children: _newList.map((task)
    {
      return TaskItem(task,_starTime,_endTime,_onClick);
    }
    ).toList());

 }
}
```

Comment: how can I combine my lists?

Comment: lib/screens/taskdetail_notscreen.dart:21:42: Error: The argument type 'List<Task>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Task'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Task' is from 'package:bmi_calculator/screens/task_notscreen.dart' ('lib/screens/task_notscreen.dart').
          return TaskItem(task,_starTime,_endTime,_onClick);
                                         ^

Comment: This is my task item: TaskItem(this._task,this._startime, this._endtime, this._onClick);

  final Task _task;
  final Task _startime;
  final Task _endtime;
  final Function _onClick;

Comment: issue is with TaskItem(task,_starTime,_endTime,_onClick)